how to interpret the decoration from git log --decorate
The output of git log --decorate is shown as follows. I'm not sure what do these decorations mean and I don't see any information about this topic on Google. Could someone enlighten me?
(origin/CBTTDSLSL-2716, CBTTDSLSL-2716)
(origin/master-E2EReonPH2-June2024-release, master-PB)
there may be one or two branches listed in the parenthesis.
the two branches listed in the parenthesis may be same or different.
what is the relationship between them?
...
| | * commit b641780 (origin/CBTTDSLSL-2716, CBTTDSLSL-2716)
| | | Author: joe <joe.doe@abc.com>
| | | Date:   10 weeks ago
| | |
| | |     CBTTDSLSL-2716: remove unused code
| | |
| | * commit 1db37e3
| | | Author: joe <joe.doe@abc.com>
| | | Date:   10 weeks ago
| | |
| | |     CBTTDSLSL-2716: pass through pointCategory
| | |
| | * commit 6eac2a4
| | | Author: joe <joe.doe@abc.com>
| | | Date:   10 weeks ago
| | |
| | |     CBTTDSLSL-2716: add checking for pointCategory
| | |
| | * commit 7dfa6fa
| |/  Author: joe <joe.doe@abc.com>
| |   Date:   10 weeks ago
| |
| |       CBTTDSLSL-2716: suppport BPO pointCategory
| |
* | commit 5b5a5ce
| | Author: joe <joe.doe@abc.com>
| | Date:   2 weeks ago
| |
| |     uat-cc-manifest.yml edited online with Bitbucket
| |
* |   commit ff14335 (origin/master-E2EReonPH2-June2024-release, master-PB)
|\ \  Merge: d3b5838 db7d50c
| | | Author: steve <steve.tom@abc.com>
| | | Date:   4 weeks ago
| | |
| | |     Pull request #154: Feature/Test merge chassis to master PB
...


They're ref names, as the docs say - branches, tags, stashes, ...

what is the relationship between the two branches listed in the parenthesis?

What does "relationship" mean? Branches do not have "relationships". A branch is just a commit name. A commit can have more than one name. I see four branches in your screen shot: origin/CBTTDSLSL-2716 and CBTTDSLSL-2716 (those are two names for one commit) and origin/master-E2EReonPH2-June2024-release and master-PB (those are two names for another commit).

The origin/ names indicate that this is a remote-tracking branch. So in the first example, origin/CBTTDSLSL-2716 is the remote tracking branch name for this commit, and CBTTDSLSL-2716 is the local branch name for this commit.

The decoration in parentheses is due to the use of the default value of --decorate, auto, which will

Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---decorateshortfullautono
This list of references is filtered by default as discussed in the documentation of the configuration option for this behaviour:

references are used as decoration if they match HEAD, refs/heads/, refs/remotes/, refs/stash/, or refs/tags/.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---decorate-refsltpatterngt

The parentheses do not indicate any pairing or relationship between the refs. The parentheses are simply to provide a container for the list of refs, which are listed together as they are for the same commit, since any number of branches or other refs can point at a single commit.
Any number of remote refs, such as branches for the origin remote, can be pointed at a commit. Separately, any number of local branches can be pointed at a commit. Whether the remote branch with the same name as a local branch are pointed at the same commit or not does not change the behaviour of the decoration.


| | * commit b641780 (origin/CBTTDSLSL-2716, CBTTDSLSL-2716)


In your case, the local branch CBTTDSLSL-2716 is pointed at commit b641780, and the remote ref origin/CBTTDSLSL-2716 for the branch of the same name is also pointed at b641780. Whether CBTTDSLSL-2716's upstream is set to origin/CBTTDSLSL-2716 is irrelevant for the decoration — they are just two branches (one local, one remote) that are pointed at the same commit.

ff14335 (origin/master-E2EReonPH2-June2024-release, master-PB)


This is similar in that there is once again one remote ref and one local ref. There is still no ‘connection’ between the two refs other than they both happen to be pointing at the same commit.
